# Port Forwarding Issues Linux

Tags: linux, portforwarding

I am running a Ripple-Rest server on a CrunchBang Linux (Debian) computer. It runs on the port 5990. I ran the server on this computer and it works fine when i view it via localhost but after port forwarding 5990 on my router I cannot acces this server from any other computer via public IP. I have given full permissions to all of the files the server uses as well.

Below are links to screen shots of what I have done:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108273736/capture.png

Please let me know what I can do to get this to work!

Comment: This question can technically be seen as within the scope of Stack Overflow but I really think you'll get a better answer on Server Fault.

Comment: Does your ISP allows port forwarding?

Comment: Yes it does allow port forwarding. I am able to ssh and access my website remotely (ports 22 and 80 are successfully forwarded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best way to do this is proxy it through nginx. That way you can use standard port for accessing the service and leave the ripple-rest service as local.

```
apt-get install nginx

change /etc/nginx/sites_enabled/default
... add in the following.. 



server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name yourservername.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5990;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that port 5990 is blocked either from your isp or iptables. You could check on remote if connections to 5990 are allowed by iptables if it is running thst is.

If you would like to run a listener on 80 that forwsrds to 5990 on remote or you could run local port forwarding.
http://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html
Assuming ssh on 22 is almost always open.

We faced a similar issue on amazon ec2 and our data center:

http://khanna111.com/wordPressBlog/2013/01/05/amazon-web-service-aws-and-vnc/

Comment: Its probably the iptables. How would i change that in the iptable?